# Is there a way to take a screenshot on a Surface RT in a full screen remote desktop session?

Tags: remote-desktop, screenshot, microsoft-surface

That pretty much says it all.  I've tried the home-key+volume button method, but it doesn't work when in a full-screen remote desktop session.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you/can you disable the pass through of Windows keys in the RT RDP client's connection options (like you can under "local resources" on the desktop version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XY Problem:](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) use the snipping tool instead.